# Git hub push of Angular project always uploads default file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to push my Angular Folder to my Git repository, but it's always uploading the default file.
Using Visual Studio Code.
The Git : https://github.com/Honigeintopf/Learning
[image]
Do i have to put all the Changes to Staged Changes or Changes?

The push is working, but it's kind of like I said always uploading the default file.

Comment: `git push` does not push *files*. The `git push` command sends (pushes) *commits*. Commits then contain files: each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file. But you have to make a new commit first. Git itself has a complicated model by which it goes about making commits, involving first "staging" your work, then committing it; you'll need to look into how VSCode does it unless you use Git from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

First, your VSCode shows staged files: you still need to make a commit locally, to have anything to push.

Second, your `git push` to `Ebu` returned:

```
repository not found 'https://github.com/Honigeintopf/Learning-'
```

That is because the actual URL of your repository is https://github.com/Honigeintopf/Learning (no trailing `-`)

Change it with:

```
cd /path/to/repository
git remote set-url Ebu https://github.com/Honigeintopf/Learning
```